# how update mongo4.0.28 in docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker

i use
docker run --name db -d mongo:4.0 --smallfiles --replSet rs0 --oplogSize 128

docker exec -ti db mongo --eval "printjson(rs.initiate())"

Then start Rocket.Chat linked to this mongo instance:

docker run --name rocketchat -p 80:3000 --link db --env ROOT_URL=http://localhost --env MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://db:27017/local -d rocket.chat
now mongo 4.0 is depricated.
how can i upgrade mongo in docker?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

1. Create mongo dump

   `docker exec -i db /usr/bin/mongodump --username <username> --password <password> --authenticationDatabase admin --db <database_name> --out dump`
2. Run new mongo container

   `docker run -d --name dbnew -i mongo:4.4 --smallfiles --replSet rs0 --oplogSize 128`
3. Restore dump to new container

   `docker cp dbnew:/dump dump`
   `docker exec -i dbnew /usr/bin/mongorestore --username <username> --password <password> --authenticationDatabase admin --db <database_name> /dump/<database_name>`
4. Check new db works fine and remove old container
5. Rename new container

   `docker rename dbnew db`

---

If you want your new container to be persistent (which I think you would) you need to use docker volumes.

Comment: ill lost all my data at  mongo4.0

Comment: i want to  upgrade from mongo 4.0.28-to 4.2   , then 4.2-4.4. i have a  data  in mongo

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fsBcCiG1AGk&t=1s   there is manual but  it  is  not good for me, because  i dont use  docker-compose